# XPath select HTML

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

How do I select "SomeText2" using HtmlAgilityPack for C#? I've tried `var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div[@class='hello']/br")` but that doesn't seem to do it right.

```
<div class="hello">SomeText1<br />
SomeText2</div>
```

Comment: You want an XPath expression that identifies the latter text node in every `div` with `class=hello`. Or the text node after the last `br` element? Or maybe the one after the first? Please explain yourself, include some more examples.

Comment: @Carlo Cannas, I want the text node after the last br element, yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your XPath expression from

```
"/div[@class='hello']/br"
```

to

```
"/div[@class='hello']/br[last()]/following-sibling::text()[1]"
```

That would be the first text node after the last `<br/>` element child of the `<div>` that has `class='hello'`.

Answer (score 1):

or this one selecting last text node inside a div

```
/div[@class='hello']/child::text()[last()]
```